# Calculate filtered averages - power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a table with broker names, the values they provide and the years they provided them in.

| Broker | Value | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 2020 |
| A | 200 | 2021 |
| B | 400 | 2020 |
| B | 500 | 2021 |

On my dashboard, there is a single select slicer for the Broker. I would like to have a line and stacked column chart. The column would have the slicer selected broker Value by Year. The line i would like is an average Value of A & B by year. So, suppose i select A on my slicer, then the visual should have two columns at 100 and 200 for year 2020 and 2021 respectively. The line should show 250 and 350 respectively.

I have tried creating a measure called consensus

`Consensus = CALCULATE(SUM(Broker[Value])/DISTINCTCOUNT(Broker[Broker]), ALLSELECTED())`

This gives me the average across all years (300) and plots them irresptive of the year.

How do I get my measure to take account of the X axis (Year).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this measure:

```
Consensus = 
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(Broker[Value]),
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Broker[Broker])
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT(Broker, Broker[Year])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing @peter, that worked. 

I also managed to get this with a bunch of googling this morning, which seems to work too:  

Consensus = CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(SUMMARIZE(Broker,Broker[Broker],Broker[Year],"val", SUM(Broker[Value])),[val]), ALL(Broker[Broker]))

I like your solution better though as it makes more sense. Thank you